# How do I resize a UITableViewCell according to the size of a UITextView subView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextview

Currently I can successfully resize my UITextView according to the amount of text within it.

My problem is that this UITextView is within a UITableViewCell. What I've tried to do is use the height of the resized UITextView to resize the cell by accessing it's frame and setting the height of that.

This is my code:

```
          //dynamically resize textview and cell based on content
                self.aboutMeTextView.text = profile["aboutMe"] as String
                self.aboutMeTextView.sizeToFit()
                self.aboutMeTextView.layoutIfNeeded()
                var frame = self.aboutMeTextView.frame as CGRect
                frame.size.height = self.aboutMeTextView.contentSize.height
                self.aboutMeTextView.frame = frame

                var cellFrame = self.aboutMeCell.frame as CGRect
                cellFrame.size.height = self.aboutMeTextView.contentSize.height * 2

                self.aboutMeCell.frame = cellFrame
```

It just doesn't work properly. The textView resizes but the cell doesn't resize properly and also my scrollView won't even scroll down enough for me to see the whole of the resized textview. I'm guessing if I can successfully set the cells height, the scrollView height will automatically adjust.

I've looked at similar questions but they haven't helped me.

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Check out [heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UITableView`-method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

[API Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

It returns the height for a row. So you can use the label from the current cell and set the height of the cell to the height of the label:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var cellID = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)  as UITableViewCell

    var yourLabelHeight = cell.yourLabel.size.height
    return yourLabelHeight
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it's a static cell. I've tried to use the returned indexPath to set specific row heights but then I just get a bunch of constraint errors

Comment: Does this still work? I think i cannot create a cell in the heightForRow in my tableView. Im using a tableView not a tableView controller.

Comment: Its not a good solution to dequeue a cell in `heightForRow` delegate method. you can calculate the size of string by providing font and font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can call UITableView.beginUpdates() and UITableView.endUpdates() like so:

```
    extension TableViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {

        var delegate: TableViewController!
        var row: Int!

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

            delegate.tableView.beginUpdates()
            delegate.tableView.endUpdates()

        }

    }


    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.rowHeight = 44
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

            cell.delegate = self
            cell.row = indexPath.row

            return cell

        }

    }
```

Be sure your constraints are set up for your text view in the table view cell.

Comment: This solution will only work if the case is `UILabel`

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas It looks like I got it to work this way. Are you sure? What error does my solution cause?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas Make sure you disable scrolling on the `UITextView` with `textView.isScrollEnabled = false`